# An app is set up based on sample App from apple website. Why does the App always crash after taking three photos?

Tags: swift, camera

Everyone,
I build an App based on the sample camera app from Apple website. The link is as below: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/sample-apps/capturingphotos-camerapreview#introduction.
I only change a little to save the photo captured and show it in another view. My codes about it are below:
After I took three photos, the app always crashes. What's the reason about it? Xcode is 15. The platform is iOS17.0

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import AVFoundation
import SwiftData

struct sCameraView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = DataModel()

    @State private var showCapturedPhoto = false
    
    private static let barHeightFactor = 0.15
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var cancelButton: some View {
        
        Button {
            dismiss()
        }label:{
            Image(systemName: "multiply")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        
    }
    
    var capturedPhotoButton: some View {
        Button {
            showCapturedPhoto = true
        } label: {
                    if model.thumbnailImage != nil {
                        model.thumbnailImage?
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                            .animation(.spring(), value: 1.0)
                        
                    } else {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
        }
    }
    
    private func buttonsView() -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: 60) {
            
            Spacer()
            
            capturedPhotoButton
            
            //take photo button
            Button {
                model.camera.takePhoto()
            } label: {
                Label {
                    Text("Take Photo")
                } icon: {
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .strokeBorder(.white, lineWidth: 3)
                            .frame(width: 62, height: 62)
                        Circle()
                            .fill(.white)
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            //switch camera button
            Button {
                model.camera.switchCaptureDevice()
            } label: {
                Label("Switch Camera", systemImage: "arrow.triangle.2.circlepath")
                    .font(.system(size: 36, weight: .bold))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
        .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
        .padding()
    }
   
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack() {
                    cancelButton
                    
                    ViewfinderView(image:  $model.viewfinderImage )
                        .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                            Color.black
                                .opacity(0.75)
                                .frame(height: geometry.size.height * Self.barHeightFactor)
                        }
                        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                            buttonsView()
                                .frame(height: geometry.size.height * Self.barHeightFactor)
                                .background(.black.opacity(0.75))
                        }
                        .overlay(alignment: .center)  {
                            Color.clear
                                .frame(height: geometry.size.height * (1 - (Self.barHeightFactor * 2)))
                                .accessibilityElement()
                                .accessibilityLabel("View Finder")
                                .accessibilityAddTraits([.isImage])
                        }
                        .background(.black)
                }
                
                
            }
            .task {
                await model.camera.start()
                await model.loadPhotos()
                await model.loadThumbnail()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Camera")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .statusBar(hidden: true)
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showCapturedPhoto) {
            CapturedPhotoView()
        }
        .environmentObject(model)
    }

}

import SwiftUI

struct CapturedPhotoView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: DataModel
    @EnvironmentObject var userViewModel : CurrentUserViewModel
    
    @State private var toNewNote = false
    @State private var toEditNote = false
    @State private var toRealizedDream = false
    @State private var toRealizedMilestone = false
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack {
                if model.thumbnailImage != nil{
                    model.thumbnailImage?
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
                        .animation(.spring(), value:1.0)
                } else {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                
                
            }
        }
        
        
        //Button
        HStack {
            
            Spacer()
            
            //Retake Button
            Button {
                dismiss()
                }
        label: {
                Text("Retake")
                    .frame(width:60,height:60)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(.red)
                    .background(Circle() )
                    .cornerRadius(30)
                    .padding(.trailing,15)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            //Save Button
            Button {
                let image = model.thumbnailImage?.asUIImage()
                let data = image?.pngData()
                userViewModel.NotePhotoDatas.append(data ?? Data())
                toNewNote = true
            } label: {
                Text("Save")
                    .frame(width:60,height:60)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(.blue)
                    .background(Circle() )
                    .cornerRadius(30)
                    .padding(.trailing,15)
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $toNewNote){
                NewNoteView(filterForTheUser: userViewModel.userID ?? "", userImageID: userViewModel.userImageID ?? "")
                            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        }
}

public extension UIView {
// This is the function to convert UIView to UIImage
    func asUIImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it say it crashed? What's the error message(s)?

Comment: The app exits and a purple warning shows The request of a upload task should not contain a body or a body stream, use `upload(for:fromFile:)`, `upload(for:from:)`, or supply the body stream through the `urlSession(_:needNewBodyStreamForTask:)` delegate method.      The purple warning is tagged on a line of code that I haven't written :postRequestTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:request.HTTPBody];. I don't know why the line of code shows.